# Как вывести повторяющееся поля один раз?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Нужна помощь.

Есть база:

```
1: Яндекс
2: Google
3: Yahoo
4: Яндекс
5: Яндекс
6: Mail.ru
и т.д.
```

Задача: выводить в список повторяющиеся поля только один раз и подсчитать сколько таких повторяющихся.

Итог:

```
Google = 1
Яндекс = 3
Mail.ru = 1
Yahoo = 1
```

Помогите с решением?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил сам

```
$source_p = mysql_query("SELECT t1.`utm_source`,COUNT(t1.`id`) AS cnt
FROM `stat` t1 
WHERE  id_cabinet = '$cabinet_id' and CONCAT(t1.`utm_source`,t1.`id`) IN (
SELECT CONCAT(t2.`utm_source`,t2.`id`) AS uv 
FROM `stat` t2 WHERE  id_cabinet = '$cabinet_id'
GROUP BY uv HAVING COUNT(uv) = 1
)
GROUP BY t1.`utm_source`");
```

Answer (score 2):

"tbl" - имя таблицы, "title" - поле с названиями

```
SELECT
  `title`, COUNT(`title`) AS `cnt`
FROM 
  `tbl`
GROUP BY 
  `title`
```

[Пример в песочнице](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bf8c/1/0)

Comment: твое решение идеально. мое за мудрено как-то медленно пашет.